# How to remove already installed provisioning profiles from the iphone on IOS7

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

My Client needs to remove a bad provisioning profile from his iphone with IOS7 installed.
Earlier with older IOS versions I was able to remove the profiles from Settings -> Profiles

But on IOS 7 how can I achieve the same result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in Settings > General > Profiles on iOS 7

It's the second to last item in the table, just above Reset.

Comment: Above reset I have VPN.

Comment: The answer is ok. I should add. At least 1 provisioning profile should be installed if you want to see the Profiles item in the Menu.